# Can't connect to Oracle with Glassfish JDBC connection pool, AccessControlException is thrown

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, glassfish

When I try to ping Oracle 11g from Glassfish 3 admin console I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword" "read")
       at com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.SSLUtils.checkPermission(SSLUtils.java:336)
       at com.sun.enterprise.security.J2EESecurityManager.checkProperty(J2EESecurityManager.java:146)
       at com.sun.enterprise.security.J2EESecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(J2EESecurityManager.java:131)
       at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:744)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection$1.run(PhysicalConnection.java:3117)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getSystemProperty(PhysicalConnection.java:3113)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.readConnectionProperties(PhysicalConnection.java:1300)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:517)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:228)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:207)
       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:157)
       at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:115)
       at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
       at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
       ... 61 more
```

Standalone app with the same JDBC driver works just fine. I am running Glassfish 3.1.2 on my local Ubuntu 12.04 box with Oracle 11g XE deployed as Docker image. I have AppArmor stopped, no firewalls active and no idea what it has to do with SSL. I also try to add javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword permission to Glassfish server.policy and JDK java.policy files but it didn't fix the issue.

The same Glassfish instance has a MySQL pool and there is no such error. May be I need to configure something on the Oracle server to make it work?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13753/usedriver.htm#JDBCD115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was resolved by putting Oracle JDBC driver jar file to `../glassfish/lib` instead of `../domain1/lib`.